# Trouble with negation introduction with Fitch natural deduction proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I've recently posted another question regarding natural deduction proofs and I've definitely made some progress, but I'm now stuck with a proof which seems like it could be flawed.

[image: The proof]

Now as you can see, it looks like I've got it all figured out, however you can see an error is returned for incorrect use of negation introduction. Now there seems to be a contradiction in the premises on lines 4 and 5: as per lines 9 and 10, R is true and P is false. I went with P being false (line 10) which leads to a contradiction, seemingly making the proof work out. However, I could just as well have gone with R being true (line 9), which, according to line 5, would not prove my contradiction as I must prove Q.

Am I missing something obvious here or do you think the proof is broken?

Thank you!

Comment: Replace $\neg Q$ with another letter, say $A$. Now review negation introduction. What exactly does it allow you to conclude?

Comment: HINT: The rule is called $\neg$ *Introduction*

Comment: Ah I see...so by using ¬  Introduction I changed line 13 to ¬¬Q and then created line 14 which states Q with a DNE justification. That works out. Thanks so much! I am however still perplexed by the contradiction in the premises...I guess I should just always pick the premises that proves what I am trying to do...

Comment: @GerhardusCarinus I have no idea of what you mean with *contradiction in the premisses*. Still regarding your proof, some of the lines can be eliminated, they aren't doing anything at all. Work backwards from the end to try to find them.

Comment: Thank you Git Gud - yes, I found the lines I'm not using :-) also, thank you for formatting my question properly! To explain what I mean by 'contradiction in the premises'. Looking at the example above, line 8 states R ∧ ¬P. Now, you can see I used the ¬P part of that conjunction to deduce Q (from line 4), which leads to the contradiction I am trying to prove. However, what if I decided to rather use the R part of R ∧ ¬P (which I should be able to do as it is a conjunction)? This leads to ¬Q (due to line 5) which would NOT prove my contradiction. Shouldn't all cases work out?

Comment: @GerhardusCarinus It's better that you ping someone when you want to make sure they'll read your comment.

Comment: Not all "cases" need to work out. In fact, "case" is a word only used with disjunctions. What you have here is a conjunction. You don't need any other "cases", you started somewhere, **you followed** the rules and obtained a contradiction, that's all.

Comment: @GitGud ah yes...total noob here, apologies! And thanks for the explanation. I understand that for disjunctions you need to prove all cases, but assumed that for conjunctions, all conjuncts in a premise 'should' technically work out as that is what a conjunction generally means. But I now understand that you just pick the conjunct that you see will work out, and if it does, you can just stop there and claim victory, regardless of the other conjuncts' potential outcomes. You have been a great help, thanks!

Comment: No worries $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

The justification for line 13 should be indirect proof (IP) rather than negation introduction.  Here is a correct proof using what you have done and the same proof checker:

[image]

Indirect proof can be found on page 118 of *forallx*.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

Tip: the rule of $\lnot\rm I$ *introduces* a negation.

So if a contradiction is derived from assuming a negation, we infer that a double negation is the case.   That is $\lnot Q\vdash\bot$ allows us to infer: $\vdash \lnot\lnot Q$.

Having done so, invoke the rule of double negation elimination (denoted: DNE, or $\lnot\lnot\rm E$), and infer that $\vdash Q$.